# Matlab double integral of dot product error

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, dot-product

Say I wanted to integrate

```
f=@(x) [1,0]; 
integral2( @(x,y) f(x)*f(y)' ,0,1,0,1 );
```

But this gives the error

```
Integrand output size does not match the input size.
```

Even though f is a vector, I am taking the dot product so the input size is 1x1. Ideally I want to use vector notation to compute dot products in the integrand, because I have a much more complex inner product which would be a pain to write out by hand. For 1D integrals you can set `arrayvalued` to `true`, but not for 2D.
How do I numerically double integrate a function containing a dot product?

Answer (score 2):

While your question provides wrong code, something like this reproduces your error:

```
integral2( @(x,y) f(x)*f(y)' ,0,1,0,1 );
```

The error is simply because your integral function is not in the format that `integral2` accepts. Your function needs to accept array inputs, and return array outputs of corresponding value.

i.e.

```
fun=@(x,y) f(x)*f(y)'
size(fun(0,1)) % returns 1, should return 1
size(fun([0,0],[1,1])) % returns 1, should return 2, because it has 2 inputs

% in other words, this must hold for it to be a valid function for integral2:
fun([0,0],[1,1]) == [fun(0,1), fun(0,1)]
```

Just rewrite your function so it can be evaluated in more than one `[x,y]` pair at the same time, make it a vectorized function.
Remember that the input does not need to be an anonymous function defined in one line, you are free to write a full function in a separate file, and use that for `integral2`.

Comment: Thanks, how do I rewrite the function?

Comment: I edited the answer with the correct input, thanks for that too

Comment: @MattMajic honestly, I think it's much easier if you just write it in a file and make a for loop.